# how to use cakePHP params to set unordered list items as active

Tags: cakephp, navigation, parameters

I want to be able to set a navigational list item as active by using cakePHP params. This would visually tell the visitor which page they're currently on. I've figured out how to do it for the current controller but, I'm routing specific rows in the post controller for pages such as 'about us' and it's not working even though I'm trying to check for the 'pass' param. Here's the code:

In an element called "leftNavBar.ctp' I've got the following:

```
<?php
  $current_pass = $this->params['pass'];
  $current_controller = $this->params['controller'];
?>

  <ul class="nav">
   <li class="<?php if(in_array($current_pass, array(2))){echo 'active';} ?>">
   <?php echo $this->Html->link(__("About Us",true),"/about-us") ?>
   </li>

    <li class="<?php if(in_array($current_controller, array('galleries'))){echo 'active';} ?>">
     <?php echo $this->Html->link(__("Galleries",true),"/galleries") ?>
    </li> 
  </ul>
```

This is the router instructions for the 'about us' page:

```
    Router::connect('/about-us',array
    ('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'view', 2));
```

Because the Posts controller has other rows/list items that I also want to set as active in the left nav bar, what I want to figure out is how to be able to do that?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing with luck was the following:

```
<?php
$url = $this->Html->url() ;
$current_controller = $this->params['controller'];
?>

<ul class="nav">
 <li <?php if($url == '/NAME-OF-URL-HERE/about-us') echo 'class="active"';?>>
 <?php echo $this->Html->link(__("About Us",true),"/about-us") ?>
 </li>

  <li class="<?php if(in_array($current_controller, array('galleries'))){echo 'active';} ?>">
   <?php echo $this->Html->link(__("Galleries",true),"/galleries") ?>
  </li> 
</ul>
```

This works well since not all URLS are handled the same way. Some URLs are controllers, others are specific IDs within controllers.

Hope this helps others.

Paul

Answer (score 0):

```
You can try setting variable inside the controller and access in view like 

In Controller

function view($id) {
  ..........
  ..........

  $this->set('current_pass',$id);

}

In View 

<?php
  $current_controller = $this->params['controller'];
?>

  <ul class="nav">
   <li class="<?php if(in_array($current_pass, array(2))){echo 'active';} ?>">
   <?php echo $this->Html->link(__("About Us",true),"/about-us") ?>
   </li>

    <li class="<?php if(in_array($current_controller, array('galleries'))){echo 'active';} ?>">
     <?php echo $this->Html->link(__("Galleries",true),"/galleries") ?>
    </li> 
  </ul>
```

Comment: thanks Bobby, I tried that without any luck. I'll add my solution below.